# How to insert results of fetch of model in a view

Tags: backbone.js

I've `fetch()` a model by a server and I want to render the results of `fetch()` with a view.

The results of `fetch()` is an array of objects (`var risultati`) and I want render this `var risultati`. I've tried but nothing works.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
    },
    initialize: function () {},
    list: function () {
        var utente = new Person();
        var risultati;
        utente.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                var ris = data.attributes;
                var risultati = ris.results;
                console.log(risultati); /* risultati contains array of object to render*/
            }
        });
        this.page = new UserListView({
            model: this.utente
        });
        $('body').append(this.page.$el);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be having problems because your call to render the view is occurring separate from your `utente.fetch()` call.

Since `.fetch()` is asynchronous, your view code will be executed before `.fetch()` has finished. You should add the view creation/rendering as part of the success function, or you should bind the change event that occurs when the model is updated to fire off a new function that contains your view creation.

Comment: Or better, `UserListView` should bind to the model's `"change"` event and its `render` should be smart enough to handle an empty model or a populated model.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your MVC logic... don't attach objects (collections I think) to a router route handler.
Assuming that you are trying to render a collection of person models, I suggest you use a model and view for the person and a collection and a view for handling the "array of objects" :

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize : function(){
            // initialize the view
            this.view = new PersonView({model : this}); 
        }
    }),
    PersonView = Backbonke.View.extend({
        render : function(){
            // render your person
        }
    }),
    UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Person,
        initialize : function(){
             this.view = new UserListView({
                  collection : this
             });
        },
        update : function(){
            var self = this;
            this.fetch({
                success: function (data) {
                    var ris = data.attributes;
                    var risultati = ris.results;
                    console.log(risultati); /* risultati contains array of object to render*/                self.view.render();
                 }
            });
        }
    }),
    UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render : function(){
            this.collection.each(function(el,i){
                el.view.render();
            });
        }
    });
```

and then use it as :

```
 var page = new UserList();
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
    },
    initialize: function () {},
    list: function () {
        page.update();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!